# Процесс "отличия" или "отличения"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В тексте идет речь о способностях детей различать формы глагола. Но вот сам процесс, когда отличают одну форму от другой, можно назвать "отличием" или "отличением"?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отличением. Слово "отличие" нужного вам значения не имеет.

> отличе́ние
> ср.
>  1. Процесс действия по гл. отличить, отличать 1.
>  2. Результат такого действия.
>
> отли́чие
> ср.
> 1.Признак, создающий разницу между данным предметом и другими.
>  Поступок, которым отличился кто-либо. 
> 2.Знак, звание, грамота и т.п., присуждаемые в ознаменование чьих-либо заслуг.

По Ефремовой.

Answer (score 2):

> В тексте идет речь о способностях детей различать формы глагола.

От глагола различать процесс будет называться словом различение, а от отличать - отличение.